# http basic authentication from java webstart

Tags: java, java-web-start

how do I use basic authentication from java webstart?
if I simply require authentication on a directory, jws requires login for every jar included in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably nothing you can do about that in itself. If you desperately want to protect your code from something, you should probably write a small, unprotected "bootstrapper" that uses JNLP's ExtensionLoaderService to load the rest of the code, doing authentication manually.

Comment: I just need something to authenticate users of this webstart app, do I have to create a custom authentication gui?

Comment: Yes, if you want to do it correctly, you do have to create a custom Gui for that. In fact, I don't think there's even any guarantee that JNLP clients other than Sun's own are even capable of doing HTTP authentication.